# How to hide the Standard Field (Name) from the Layout

Tags: fields, object, admin

I have created an object named "Bus". By default, a field called **Bus Name** has been created in this object. However, I don't need this field based on my scenario and requirement. Is there any way to remove or hide it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you edit the object to change the name field data type to "auto-number", you can then remove it from the page layout. However, you can't remove it entirely, as the name field is used in lookup fields and will appear in reports.

Comment: Just want to reiterate what Fox is saying here - if you turn "Bus Name" into an auto number, that means any lookup that you populate with a Bus will only show the auto generated number - which may be confusing to end users depending on your use case. Users may find it challenging to link records to the correct bus.